# Matlibplot step function index 0

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to plot this using matplotlib's step function

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import step, show, xlim

time = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.3039, 25.5539, 25.8049, 45.8699, 46.1209, 46.3719, 46.6229, 63.1719, 63.4239, 63.6749, 79.9779, 80.2289, 80.4799, 80.7309]
value = ['0', '0', '0', '93', '940', '951', '940', '437', '422', '421', '423', '598', '605', '192', '3', '1', '0']

xlim(0, 145)
step(time,value)

show()
```

I am hoping the step function will show the plot to be 0 and starts at 93 from time 25.3039. Instead I see value 93 from time 0 as shown in the graph. I need to keep the timeline to start from 0 so I can't really change my xlim to start from 25.3039

What should I do to fix the issue? Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set where step should step ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.step)).  The default is that the locations are interpreted as the *right* edge, you want the locations interpreted as the *left* edge.

```
step(time,value,where='post')
```

See [Step function in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841847/step-function-in-python) for a longer explanation/example.