# Step function in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have seen some questions asked about step functions in matplotlib but this one is different.
Here is my function:

```
def JerkFunction(listOfJerk):
    '''Return the plot of a sequence of jerk'''
    #initialization of the jerk
    x = np.linspace(0,5,4)
    y = listOfJerk #step signal

    plt.axis([0,5,-2,2])
    plt.step(x,y,'y') #step display
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('Jerk (m/s^3)')

    plt.title('Jerk produced by the engine')

    return plt.show()
```

I would like to have the curve obtained when I put `JerkFunction([1,1,-1,1])` but by entering: `[1,-1,1,-1]`, indeed, at the beginning, in a real case, the jerk value is 0 and at `t=0`, it becomes `jerk=+1`, then at `t=`1 it is `Jerk=-1` etc.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: What is your problem? I see a description of the result, but there doesn't seem to be any problem. What are your expectations (eg, for particular use case), what are the actual results?

Comment: Your `JerkFunction()` doesn't actually do anything, and unless this entire block of code is in a function, your `return plt.show()` is a syntax error.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: Note that the documentation states:  **y**: array like
        1-D sequence, and it is assumed, but not checked, that it is uniformly increasing.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are having the same problem this question [Matlibplot step function index 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755717/matlibplot-step-function-index-0/12756041#12756041).  The issue you are having is related to where step changes the value in relation to the x values ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.step)).

The following demonstrates the three ways it can do this.  The curves are shifted vertically for clarity.  The horizontal dashed lines are 'zero' and the vertical dotted lines are your x values.

```
x = np.linspace(0,5,3)
y = np.array([1,-1,1])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.step(x,y,color='r',label='pre')
ax.step(x,y+3,color='b',label='post',where='post')
ax.step(x,y+6,color='g',label='mid',where='mid')
for j in [0,3,6]:
    ax.axhline(j,color='k',linestyle='--')
for j in x:
    ax.axvline(j,color='k',linestyle=':')
ax.set_ylim([-2,9])
ax.set_xlim([-1,6])
ax.legend()

ax.draw()
```

[image: example of three step location options]

Comment: Yeah it is the blue curve that I needed, tks you. I now have my step function and its integrate signal, a triangle function.Any idea of how I can integrate my triangle function? cause I see some function predifined in scipy but it return numbers and I want a curve, more exactly parabolas.

Comment: @Ponzi If this answered your question, you should accept this answer and then ask a new question about how to integrate the triangle function.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but I think this may produce the plot you are looking for. If this is not what you are looking for it will be easier to assist you with more information.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,5,4)
y = [1,1,-1,1]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.step(x,y)
ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax.set_ylabel(r'Jerk ($m/s^3$)')
ax.set_ylim((-1.5,1.5))
ax.set_title('Jerk Produced by the Engine')

plt.show()
```

[image: Example Plot]