# Draw a step histogram without closing the polygon with the bottom line

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I remove the bottom line that closes the path of a step histogram?

[image]

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, 50, normed=1, histtype='step')
plt.ylim(-.005, plt.ylim()[1])
plt.show()
```

**UPDATE:** reported and now fixed:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2113

Comment: I don't get this line using mpl 1.1.0

Comment: Good point. I didn't either. I am now using the HEAD and see the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just plot it your self:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
bins, edges = np.histogram(x, 50, normed=1)
ax.step(edges[:-1], bins, where='post')
plt.ylim(-.005, plt.ylim()[1])
plt.show()
```

See [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.step) or [Step function in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841847/step-function-in-matplotlib/12846384#12846384) to understand `where=post`.  You need to chop the last entry off edges because histogram returns `[left_edege_0, left_edge_1, ..., left_edge_(n-1), right_edge_(n-1)]`  (see
[doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html))

This has been deemed a regression, and will be fixed in at least 1.3. Relevant PR: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2113

Comment: Thanks, works very well! Would mpl devs ever consider adding an option to turn off the bottom line in pyplot.hist? As @tom10 mentioned above this was the previous behaviour.

Comment: @ndawe There was a bunch of work done on histograms recently, this might be a regression.  I suspect this is a consequence of the work ot add filled step plots.  You should create an issue on github.