# Can we draw digital waveform graph with Pyplot in python or Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, graph, matplotlib

I am trying to draw digital signal waveform graph for bits like 01010101010101 using pyplot in python, like

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Differential_manchester_encoding.svg/600px-Differential_manchester_encoding.svg.png]

Is it possible with Pyplot?

Comment: this can be done using `plot`, but it requires a little tweak of the input coordinates: whenever there is a change in the signal an additional point should be added to the sequence with the same time *x coordinate) and appropriate zero-one value for the y coordinate. I do not have Matlab open right now to provide a detailed solution, but this info should be enough to implement one.

Comment: In matlab: [stairs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As noted by tcaswell, the right function to use is `step`. Here an example that approximates your given plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def my_lines(ax, pos, *args, **kwargs):
    if ax == 'x':
        for p in pos:
            plt.axvline(p, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        for p in pos:
            plt.axhline(p, *args, **kwargs)

bits = [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0]
data = np.repeat(bits, 2)
clock = 1 - np.arange(len(data)) % 2
manchester = 1 - np.logical_xor(clock, data)
t = 0.5 * np.arange(len(data))

plt.hold(True)
my_lines('x', range(13), color='.5', linewidth=2)
my_lines('y', [0.5, 2, 4], color='.5', linewidth=2)
plt.step(t, clock + 4, 'r', linewidth = 2, where='post')
plt.step(t, data + 2, 'r', linewidth = 2, where='post')
plt.step(t, manchester, 'r', linewidth = 2, where='post')
plt.ylim([-1,6])

for tbit, bit in enumerate(bits):
    plt.text(tbit + 0.5, 1.5, str(bit))

plt.gca().axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just use `plt.step`

```
plt.step(x, y, where='pre')
```

See [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.step) and [Linestyle in matplotlib step function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188005/linestyle-in-matplotlib-step-function/15191183#15191183)  and [Step function in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841847/step-function-in-matplotlib/12846384#12846384) for examples.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt. The trick I've used is to double-up each x and y-coordinate with `np.repeat` and then offset them by 1 to generate the coordinates of each corner. Let me know if this needs better explanation. You can add grid lines with `plt.grid(True)`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
xs = np.repeat(range(len(data)), 2)
ys = np.repeat(data, 2)
xs = xs[1:]
ys = ys[:-1]
xs = np.append(xs,xs[-1] + 1)
ys = np.append(ys, ys[-1])
plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.ylim(-0.5, 1.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since your title also says "in Matlab": use [`stairs`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html):

```
y = [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]; % define values
stairs(0:length(y)-1,y) % do the plotting
ylim([-.5 1.5]) % adjust axis limits
```

[image]